# openGL: glGenVertexArrays Access violation executing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to learn openGL myself so I bought a book about openGL and in first chapter are example code so I try it and something went wrong. At line                            17(glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);) and 18(glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);) is VS 2013 Ultimate report an error exactly "Unhandled exception at 0x77350309 in openGL_3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.". So I think it's something wrong with memory but i do not know what. Can someone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <vgl.h>
#include <LoadShaders.h>


enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers };
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0 };
GLuint VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint Buffers[NumBuffers];
const GLuint NumVertices = 6;

void init(void)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][2] = {
        { -0.90, -0.90 }, // Triangle 1
        { 0.85, -0.90 },
        { -0.90, 0.85 },
        { 0.90, -0.85 }, // Triangle 2
        { 0.90, 0.90 },
        { -0.85, 0.90 }
    };
    glGenBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices),
    vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ShaderInfo shaders[] = {
        { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert" },
        { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag" },
        { GL_NONE, NULL }
    };
    GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
    glUseProgram(program);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT,
    GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    if (glewInit()) {
        cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW ... exiting" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try setting:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
```

before your call to `glewInit()`. Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822876/833188

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22820845/833188

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you can request version `4.3` **before** call to `glewInit()`? Every version `>= 3.0` requires [`WGL_ARB_create_context (Windows)`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt)/[`GLX_ARB_create_context (Linux)`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/glx_create_context.txt), which is an extension.

Usually, to create *"modern"* OpenGL context (3.0+) it is required to:

1. Create temporary context, set it as current.
2. Initialize extensions (either manually or with loader like `GLEW` or `GLFW`).
3. Request desired version (and profile, if you create version `3.2` or higher and `WGL_ARB_create_context_profile`/`GLX_ARB_create_context_profile` is present).
4. Delete temporary context from `1.` and bind your new context.

You may want to look at:

- [OpenGL 3.0 Context Creation (GLX)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_%28GLX%29#The_Code)
- [OpenGL 3.1 The First Triangle (WGL)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_%28C%2B%2B/Win%29#Rendering_Context_Creation)

I do not know, what is the connection between requesting context version in `GLUT` and `GLEW` initialization (I often use `GLEW`, but creation of context is something, that I **always** do manually, with platform-specific API), but obviously, pointers to new OpenGL API are not initialized when you call `glGenVertexArrays`. That is the reason of your error - you try to call function via pointer, which is `NULL`.

Comment: freeglut (and the whole `glutInitContextVersion` API is just a freeglut-specific extension not present in other GLUT versions) will hanlde the context creation in a platform-abstracted manner, just like GLFW, SDL or similiar libs. There is actually no prinicpal problem with that approach, besides trying to use `glewInit()` without `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE` in a core profile.

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree to Sga's answer recommending to set `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE` before calling `glewInit()`. GLEW will fail to initialize in a core profile if this option is not set.

However, the fact that the `glewInit()` does *not* fail implies that the OP did not get a core profile at all (or that GLEW has finally been fixed, but that is more of a theoretical possibility).

I already had a look into freeglut's implementation of the (freeglut-specific) `glutInitContextVersion` API for the question "[Where is the documentation for glutInitContextVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958770/where-is-the-documentation-for-glutinitcontextversion/27972098#27972098)", and the conclusions from back then might be helpful in this case. To quote myself:

> From looking into the code (for the current stable version 2.8.1), one
>   will see that freeglut implements the following logic: If the
>   implementation cannot fullfill the version constraints, but does
>   support the ARB_create_context extension, it will generate some error
>   and no context will be created. However, if a version is requested,
>   but the implementation does not even support the relevant extensions,
>   a legacy GL context is created, effectively ignoring the version
>   request completely.

So from the reported behavior, I deduce that the OP did only get a *legacy context*, possibly even Microsofts default OpenGL 1.1 implementation.

This also expalins why `glGenVertexArrays()` is a NULL pointer even after `glewInit()` succeeded: The extension is not supported for this context.

You should check what `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` actually return right after the `glutCreateWindow()` call. And depending on the output, you might consider checking/updating your graphics drivers, or you might learn that your GPU is just not capable of modern GL at all.